# minimizing std of linear combination of 2 lists in python

Tags: python, minimize, standard-deviation

There are 2 python lists (ndarrays, whatever...) of the same length.

```
v1 = [1, 2, 3]
v2 = [7, 8, 9]
```

I'd like to find two weights: w and (1 - w) such that `std(v1 * w + v2 * (1-w))` is minimal. Which python library does it except of scipy.optimize.minimize?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use `scipy.optimize.minimize`?

Comment: No particular reason, just would like to know what are other options.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem has a closed solution. I have given it a quick try with [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/) and, unless I did something wrong, given vectors `a = [a_1, ..., a_k]` and `b = [b_1, ..., b_k]`, the solution would be (vectors are columns, middle dot represents matrix product and *sum* is the sum of all the elements in the matrix):

[image: Solution]

Daunting.

Again, I did not reasoned this myself, I'm just trusting the output of SymPy, so you can check with some instance of the problem with a known solution and see if it works.

Edit:

A bit of background on how I got the result. To be honest, I only got the result for vectors of a fixed size (four) and "deduced" the general formula; I don't know if there is a better way to do it other than deriving it by hand (afaik SymPy does not handle matrices or vectors of undefined sizes). So anyway, once you have installed [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/), you can do:

```
import sympy

# Derivating just for k = 4
a = sympy.Matrix(sympy.symbols('a:4'))
b = sympy.Matrix(sympy.symbols('b:4'))
w = sympy.symbols('w')
c = w * a + (1 - w) * b
mean = sum(c) / len(c)
# We minimize variance, which is equivalent to minimizing standard deviation
s2 = c - mean * sympy.Matrix([1] * len(c)) # Matrices can only be add/substract other matrices
s2 = sum(s2.multiply_elementwise(s2)) / len(s2)
# Derivate wrt w
s2dw = s2.diff(w)
# Find zero of derivative
sol = sympy.solveset(s2dw, w)
# There must be only one solution
assert len(sol) == 1
sol = list(sol).pop()
# Simplify
sol = sol.simplify()
print(sol)

>>> (-3*a0*b0 + a0*b1 + a0*b2 + a0*b3 + a1*b0 - 3*a1*b1 + a1*b2 + a1*b3 + a2*b0 + a2*b1 - 3*a2*b2 + a2*b3 + a3*b0 + a3*b1 + a3*b2 - 3*a3*b3 + 3*b0**2 - 2*b0*b1 - 2*b0*b2 - 2*b0*b3 + 3*b1**2 - 2*b1*b2 - 2*b1*b3 + 3*b2**2 - 2*b2*b3 + 3*b3**2)/(3*a0**2 - 2*a0*a1 - 2*a0*a2 - 2*a0*a3 - 6*a0*b0 + 2*a0*b1 + 2*a0*b2 + 2*a0*b3 + 3*a1**2 - 2*a1*a2 - 2*a1*a3 + 2*a1*b0 - 6*a1*b1 + 2*a1*b2 + 2*a1*b3 + 3*a2**2 - 2*a2*a3 + 2*a2*b0 + 2*a2*b1 - 6*a2*b2 + 2*a2*b3 + 3*a3**2 + 2*a3*b0 + 2*a3*b1 + 2*a3*b2 - 6*a3*b3 + 3*b0**2 - 2*b0*b1 - 2*b0*b2 - 2*b0*b3 + 3*b1**2 - 2*b1*b2 - 2*b1*b3 + 3*b2**2 - 2*b2*b3 + 3*b3**2)
```

You can also check that the solution is actually a minimum because when you replace it in the second derivative it is a bunch of squared stuff (i.e. positive):

```
s2dww = s2dw.diff(w)
s2dww_sol = s2dww.subs(w, sol).simplify()
print(s2dww_sol)

>>> 2*(a0 - 2*a1 + a2 - b0 + 2*b1 - b2)**2/27 + 2*(a0 + a1 - 2*a2 - b0 - b1 + 2*b2)**2/27 + 2*(2*a0 - a1 - a2 - 2*b0 + b1 + b2)**2/27
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks! I am new to SymPy. How could I re-run the computations?

Comment: Okay I just found out I made a mistake (big surprise), let me try to fix it and I'll put some code...

Comment: @AlexanderShapiro There, I updated the answer with a (hopefully) correct formula and a bit of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what a powerful tool is this SymPy!